# Azure Policy to disallow Storage account creation

Tags: azure, azure-files, azure-policy, azure-storage-account

I'm an Azure administrator, and seems like some users can create Azure Storage Accounts without my consent. I would like to see how I can enforce a policy such that I'm the only user that can create them and other users won't be able to do so. I know there are multiple ways to do it, however I'm mostly inerested in a custom policy in Azure. I couldn't really find any examples online. Please note I'm going to use this policy so that it can overwrite any existing RBAC roles etc. Can't go any further with the JSON code below.

```
{
    "policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "allOf": [{
                    "field": "type",
                    "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
                },
                {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                    "like": "*"
                }
            ]
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost did it but with minor mistake.
HEre is working example

Create policy

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "field": "type",
      "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Then during assignment set non-complient message
[image]

So now anyone who wants to create will see this
[image]

Comment: Thanks Vova, I was looking to see if in the json code I can specificy who also can create the storage account (such as myself). Since right now it's just making sure it's disabled for everybody. How can I make some execptions for some users?

Comment: @Roham I think then policy is not what you want to do then, probably have a look into roles which will deny creating storage. Policy is all about resource you create and not about users who do that

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in, strongly typed Azure Policy Definition out there. Using it will allow you to easily block next services in the future by changing the assignment parameters.

(/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/6c112d4e-5bc7-47ae-a041-ea2d9dccd749).